# If $\lim_{x \to p} f(t)=L$ how do I prove that $\lim_{x \to p} \frac{1}{f(t)}=1/L?$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x \to p} f(t)=L$ how do I prove that $\lim_{x \to p} \frac{1}{f(t)}=1/L?$

My attempt:
$|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{L}|=\frac{|f(x)-L|}{|L||f(x)|}$

So the only thing stopping me from going on with the proof is the $|f(x)|$ term in the denominator.

Somehow, I need to show that $f(x) \geq  M$ for some $ \delta>0$ which implies $\frac{1}{f(x)} \leq \frac{1}{M}$

Can someone please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: You are assuming of course that $L \neq 0$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0:$
$$|x-p|<\delta \Rightarrow  |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$

You then get

$$|f(x)| \geq |L| - |L-f(x)| > |L| - \epsilon $$

Pick $\epsilon < |L|$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L \neq 0 \implies |f(p+\epsilon) - L |\le \delta$$ 
for a given $\delta$. Since $L \neq 0$ the second fraction you have converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more general proof assuming you know **Algebra of Continuity**

$S$ be a deleted neighborhood of $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Suppose $f,g:S\to\mathbb{R} \ni\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L,\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=M\ne 0$

$F:S\cup\{c\}\to\mathbb{R},G:S\cup\{c\}\to\mathbb{R}$

be function such that $F(c)=L,G(c)=M$ and $F(x)=f(x)\forall x\in  S,G(x)=g(x)\forall x\in S$

$F,G$ are continuous at $c$

Choose $\epsilon={M\over 2}$.

Choose $\delta>0\ni 0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow x\in S$ and $|g(x)-M|<{M\over 2}$

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but rather a remark on how it fits into a broader viewpoint.

Generally, if $G\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous function, and $x_i\to \overline x$ is a sequence of points of $X$ with limit $\overline x$ also in $X$, then $\lim_iG(x_i)=G(\overline x)$. Another way of writing this is that $\lim_iG(x_i)=G(\lim_ix_i)$. That is, you can pass the $G$ through the limit sign. This is fairly easy to show, directly from the definitions. So to give your desired proof, it suffices to show that $G(x)=1/x$ is continuous.